# lookup map values and calling matched implementations

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, polymorphism

I have the following design of my classes:

```
public interface Device {
    void create();
}

public class Printer implements Device {
    @Override
    public void create() {
}

public class Mouse implements Device {
    @Override
    public void create() {
}



public class ProcessImpl implements Processor {

   private final Map<String, Set<String>> deviceMap = new HashMap<>();

   @Override
   public void process(String input) {
       populateMap(input);

       //call to `provision(deviceMap)`

}
```

`deviceMap` values are arranged like this for example:
{123=[P, M], 224=[C, P, M]}

where `123` is an `ID` and String values `C',`P`,`M` represents devices to be created against the corresponding ID.

My question is, how can I iterate over this map in `provision(deviceMap)` method and `create` the devices by calling their corresponding `create()` method. (achieving polymorphism) e.g.

When `P` -> Call `create()` in `Printer` implementation of `Device`. What is good design/pattern I can use to structure the classes? Can `enum` help with this or is there a better cleaner approach ?

Answer (score 1):

*Apologize for the probably incorrect Java syntax and conventions (I'm a C# developer) but:*

You can have a factory that will have a mapping between the allowed strings to the `Device` types:

```
public interface IDeviceFactory {
    Device getDevice(string string input);
}

public class MappingDeviceFactory implements IDeviceFactory {

    private Map<String, Device> _mapping;

    public MappingDeviceFactory(Map<String, Device> mapping) {
        _mapping = mapping;
    }

    public Device getDevice(string string input) {
        //Look in the mapping for the input and return that device.
    }
}
```

Another way is that each device will "say" what type of input it is for:

```
public interface Device {
    String _type;
    void create();
}

public abstract class DeviceBase {
    public String _type;

    public DeviceBase(String type) {
        _type = type;
    }

    public abstract void create();
}

public class Printer implements DeviceBase {
    public Printer() super ("P") {}
    @Override
    public void create() {}
}
```

and then in your implementation of the `IDeviceFactory` from above just have instead of a mapping a collection of `Device` and search the collection according to the given `input`

---

About the `enum` vs. `String` for the mapping:

- I'd prefer going for the `enum` over the strings because it helps me prevent passing incorrect values.
- However, if you don't know all the types of `Device`s at the compilation time (meaning you can have a value for them in the `enum`; Would happen in a case that other people write more `Device`s and that you load those files in runtime) then I'd go for one of two:

  - Have an object `DeviceRequestBase` with: `PrinterDeviceRequest`, `MouseDeviceRequest`... Then the factory will map between the type if the request to the device type.
  - If this feels like an overkill and you don't need it to be so extensible - then just stick to the `string`s